# Log likelihood method for dichotomising a continuous variable?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Dichotomising a continuous variable is generally not a good idea. But if the situation demands that you must, is this a good (or even valid?) way of identifying a cut-point that retains the most explanatory and/or predictive power?

1) Identify N cut-points in your continuous variable to create N dichotomised variables
2) Fit a univariate regression model for each dichotomised variable
3) Pick the cut-point from the model with highest likelihood from 2) above

Answer (score 0):

Does the situations *really* demand that you discretize the continuous variable? If so, read on.

Provided that your continuous variable (or some transformation thereof) is approximately normal, [Gelman and Park](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/thirds5.pdf) offer a useful heuristic based on solid theoretical principles and empirical performance for trichotomizing your data with minimal loss of information.